# Jupyter run Bash command without printing output

Tags: bash, jupyter

Is there a way to run command line commands in Jupyter without the cell output?

e.g.

```
!wget http://files.fast.ai/data/dogscats.zip -P ./data/
```

without printing the process in my cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the oldest trick works:

```
!wget ... >/dev/null 2>&1
```

or with [`--err` option](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-script):

```
In [1]: %%bash --err null
    ...: wget ...
```

this actually stores the `stderr` output into the variable `null`.

Comment: great! to provide context: the null device is a device file that discards all data written to it but reports that the write operation succeeded. This device is called /dev/null on Unix and Unix-like systems.

Comment: Why did you add 2>&1 ?

Comment: @RutgerHofste wget outputs progress to stderr